# Cannot show picture from database in IE 8

Tags: css, cross-browser, jpeg

When browsing the pages of my display cart list and pictures with IE 8 , cannot show pictures ( .jpeg) and shadow effect. but other browser wroks fine..

The pictures are thumbnails that obtained from the photo album ,linked by url,

The below is my CSS.

```
body {
font-family:Helvetica-light;
font-size:14px;
padding:0;
margin:0;}

h1 {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight:normal;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#777;
    display:block;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

:focus {outline:none;}

label { display:block; margin:0 0 5px 0;}

input {
    display:block;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
}

input[type=submit] {
    cursor:pointer;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #CCC;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #CCC;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 5px #CCC;
    behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

table tr th {
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px;
    background:#F9F9F9;
}

table tr td {
    padding:10px;
}

table tr.empty td {
    background:#F9F9F9;
}


.clear { clear:both;}
.bold { font-weight:bold;}

#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
    behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
}

.notify {
    padding:10px;
    background:#E9E9E9;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

.product {
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #CCC;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #CCC;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0 5px #CCC;
    behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
}

.url{

    behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
}
    .product .info { 
    float:left;
    padding:10px;}

    .product h3 { 
        margin:0 0 5px 0;
        background:#F9F9F9;
        padding:10px;
    }
```

Comment: yes i do have terrible vision, but i dont see any image in your css

Comment: It is to load the image  through getting database query, in path rather then the image itself.
And I use the php to code

Answer (score 0):

`behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);` does not use the same path structure as `background-image: url();`

This will not look in the directory your CSS lives in, but rather the docroot of your site. Be sure that this file is accessible from http://yourwebsite.com/ie-css3.htc

Also, I would change the order of your box-shadow CSS declarations like follows:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
-o-box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC;
box-shadow:0 0 10px #CCC; /* This was moved to the bottom */
```

Since CSS "cascades", a browser that supports `box-shadow` but keeps `-webkit-box-shadow` around for legacy reasons would use the non-standard `-webkit-box-shadow` in how your code was laid out. By moving `box-shadow` to the bottom, we ensure that browsers who support the standard will use it.